# Getting title, description and number of views of a youtube video

Tags: php

```
$youtube = simplexml_load_file('http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/wGG543FeHOE?v=2');
$title = $youtube->title;
```

This gets the title. But how could I get the viewcount and description? tried `$youtube->description;` and `$youtube->views;`

Comment: There isn't a `description` or a `views` node in the xml output, you have the `<yt:statistics` node that has an attribute called `viewCount`, which stores the current view count, and a `<media:description` node which stores the description of the video

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I suggest you to use the JSON output instead of the XML one.

You can get it by adding the `alt=json` parameter to your URL:

```
http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/wGG543FeHOE?v=2&alt=json
```

Then you have to load the json and parse it:

```
<?php
$json_output = file_get_contents("http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/wGG543FeHOE?v=2&alt=json");
$json = json_decode($json_output, true);

//This gives you the video description
$video_description = $json['entry']['media$group']['media$description']['$t'];

//This gives you the video views count
$view_count = $json['entry']['yt$statistics']['viewCount'];

//This gives you the video title
$video_title = $json['entry']['title']['$t'];
?>
```

Hope this helps.

**UPDATE**

To see what variables does the JSON output have, add the `prettyprint=true` parameter to the URL and open it in your browser, it will beautify the JSON output to make it more comprehensible:

```
http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/wGG543FeHOE?v=2&alt=json&prettyprint=true
```

Instead of browsing the URL you can just write

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r($json);
echo "</pre>";
```

after

```
$json = json_decode($json_output, true);
```

and it will print the formatted JSON output

Comment: @Kaka use `print_r($json);` to see all the variables. @BackSlash +1

Comment: @Kaka check the last line of code i added, you can go to [this link](http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/wGG543FeHOE?v=2&alt=json&prettyprint=true) to see the pretty print for the JSON output

Comment: Amazing! However lets say the youtube video gets deleted. How should i handle that? Not i will get error if its a invalid id

Comment: @Kaka i guess it will output nothing if the video gets deleted, but i'm not sure

Comment: @Kaka Try `if(($json_output = file_get_contents('http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/INVALID_ID?v=2&alt=json'))){ something... } else { echo 'Error'; }`

Comment: @Kaka Just tried, if a video gets deleted, the video feed URL is not found, so the Guilherme Nascimento solution should work

Comment: after latest youtube update, this is not working, any idea how to fix this?...i mean to update the above code in order to work

Comment: @33528 Hi, I'm reading about the new API. I'll post an update!

Answer (score 6):

My code:

```
$vId = "Jer8XjMrUB4";
$gkey = "AIzaSyCO5lIc_Jlrey0aroqf1cHXVF1MUXLNuR0";

$dur = file_get_contents("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet,contentDetails&id=".$vId."&key=".$gkey."");


$data = json_decode($dur, true);
foreach ($data['items'] as $rowdata) {
     $vTime = $rowdata['contentDetails']['duration'];
     $desc = $rowdata['snippet']['description'];
}


$interval = new DateInterval($vTime);
$vsec = $interval->h * 3600 + $interval->i * 60 + $interval->s;

if($vsec > 3600)
    $vsec = gmdate("H:i:s", $vsec);
else
    $vsec = gmdate("i:s", $vsec);

echo $vsec."--".$desc;
```

Result:

02:47--Following the critically acclaimed global smash hit X-Men:

Answer (score 4):

Youtube API V2.0 has been deprecated.You must have to switch to V3 API.Which need API key.

So prefer to use but In this way so can not get video description

```
http://www.youtube.com/oembed?url=https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ktt3C7nQbbA&format=json
```